# One Slicer to control multiple date columns without affecting each other

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have multiple date columns (open date; close date;  reopen date; etc..). At the moment, to avoid this I have One slicer for each column to filter the visuals, and make sure the interactions are set so that they do not filter wrong data.

However, this way If I want to see an SLA from a particular year/month, I have to filter for each category (I have 5) So I have **5 year** and **5 month** filters on my page.

Is it somehow possible to have just one year and month filter that filters all of the categories without affecting each other?

```
  Edit: Table Sample referring to service desk tickets
  
  | Open Date | Close Date | Reopen Date
1 | 1/1/2022  | 2/1/2022   | 3/1/2022
2 | 1/1/2022  | 3/1/2022   | 3/1/2022
3 | 1/1/2022  | 3/1/2022   | 4/1/2022
4 | 2/1/2022  | 2/1/2022   | null
5 | 3/1/2022  | 6/1/2022   | null
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the 5 date columns are related, e.g. in one fact table, the slicers/columns will always affect each other.

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought. Thank you. If I create separate summary tables, will this help to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you show some sample data? And the output you wants in the report.